# Ec2 instance type for an api with complex database and data calculation

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need advise from any one who uses aws ec2 instance to host their projects.

Currently I have a php project(for backend api) and a reactjs (for frontend). When testing locally, the api response time is 3 seconds(I still optimizing my backend code to reduce it to 2 seconds), but my main concern is when deployed to a staging machine in aws using t3.medium for the backend and t2.medium for frontend, the response time is at least 19 seconds. Here are my goals

```
   1. For staging, at least 5 seconds response time, since this is mainly used for testing purposes.
   2. For production, I want the response time same as my local machine.My local machine uses i-7 and 16 gig of ram(with of course too many other application running and lots of tabs open (google chrome) locally).The initial target users for the production is 10-15 users, but will grow once our app will be tested well and stable(I mean data should be accurate).
```

At first my plan is to test all the available ec2 instance types and see which of them suits in my requirements particularly the response time, but a friend told me that it will cost me a lot since every time an ec2 instance is provisioned, aws will charge for the resources used.Also, what are the best approach, since my backend api has lot of scripts that is being run .The scripts is actually calling the amazon selling partner api and advertising api, which is currently, a very slow api itself, some of their endpoints has a response time of at least 30 seconds, that is why I decided to run them in backeground tru cron jobs.THis scripts also perform database writes after the response from amazon api is successful.

Thank you

Comment: Have you profiled your application at all to see where it's slow? If your service is using CPU all the time (like from frequent cron jobs), you do want to avoid t2 and t3 instances. AWS instances charge per-second for ec2, so you do have to pay for your test, but not any more than the time the instance is running.

Comment: For database optimization, start with the slowlog:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: @jordanm I already profiled my application and optimized those part that causes bottleneck, locally the response time is now reduced just to 2 seconds.My main concern now is which  the ec2 type should I use because t2.medium is not suitable for my application specially when the cron jobs is running .Do you have idea which ec2 type is best for this scenario ?